# Convert a collection or array of objects into a comma separated string with just one of the object properties

Tags: powershell

How do I convert a collection or array of objects into a comma-separated string with just one of the object properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the comment from Santiago Squarzon I changed my code to this:

```
$array.Id -join ','
$collection.Name -join ','
```

I originally did this:

#### Objects

```
$o1 = [PSCustomObject]@{ Name = "John"; Id = 1 }
$o2 = [PSCustomObject]@{ Name = "Jack"; Id = 2 }
$o3 = [PSCustomObject]@{ Name = "Jane"; Id = 3 }
```

#### Array

```
$array = @()
$array = $array + $o1
$array = $array + $o2
$array = $array + $o3
```

#### String of Ids

```
$commaSeparatedStringOfIds = ($array | Select-Object -Property Id | ForEach-Object { $_.Id }) -join ','
$commaSeparatedStringOfIds
```

#### Generic.List

```
$collection = New-Object Collections.Generic.List[System.Object]
$collection.Add($o1)
$collection.Add($o2)
$collection.Add($o3)
```

#### String of Names

```
$commaSeparatedStringOfNames = ($collection | Select-Object -Property Name | ForEach-Object { $_.Name }) -join ','
$commaSeparatedStringOfNames
```

Comment: Your answer is inefficient. Simply doing `$array.Id -join ','` or `$collection.Name -join ','` would have done the trick.

Comment: Great. I didn't know this trick. I updated my answer. Thanks

Comment: Also, the syntax `$array = $array + $o1` is quiet inefficient because the `$array` is mutual, see: [Why should I avoid using the increase assignment operator (`+=`) to create a collection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60708579/1701026). In other words build your collection from the pipeline: `$array = $o1, $o2, $o3`